# Deeplearning4J Android example

Tags: android, for-loop, deeplearning4j

Is there any example for usage of deeplearning4j in android. I downloaded some of the examples from deeplearning4j.org. I did not find one for android.

Comment: Or an example where I can use keras model in android for inference is also of a great use.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://deeplearning4j.org/android we don't have an explicit android example because there's nothing to do that's different in the code besides configuring the dependencies.